# Searchbox from folder without sql

Tags: php, html

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I was wondering if anybody can give me some advice on it. I got the code from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_table)   but I added my code to it and replaced names with my files from the folder. I'm trying to make it so that anybody that is on my site can click on the name of the file and it works just same as the link I show you. I got it part way to work but not understanding why it isn't working much like the link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>My Customers</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%; align:center;">Name</th> 
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <?php   
if ($file = opendir('C:/wamp/www/example.com/Library')) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($file))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") { 
print "      
 <td href='#'><a href='http://qlhc3kppkxushjyg.onion/example.com/Library/$entry'>$entry</br></a></td>
"; 
        }
    } 
        closedir($file);
}  

?>  
  </tr> 
</table>


<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the problem, error?

Comment: It isn't showing any errors; however, when typing keyword it should pop up all keywords that match it; nevertheless, it does not work like that. The link i post on there is the idea what I'm going for and i was wondering if anyone have idea or advice on it. That would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is. It's working just fine. Just one thing.. please don't use absolute paths like `$file = opendir('C:/wamp/www/example.com/Library')`, use relative paths like `$file = opendir('Library')`. This means that your current directory has *this script* and a directory called *Library* which contains all the entries you want to filter.

Example directory structure:

```
    htdocs/
    ├── Library/
    │   ├── John.txt
    │   ├── Scott.txt
    │   └── Anna.txt
    └── index.php (this script)
```

Script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        #myInput {
            background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
            background-position: 10px 10px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 16px;
            padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            margin-bottom: 12px;
        }

        #myTable {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        #myTable th, #myTable td {
            text-align: left;
            padding: 12px;
        }

        #myTable tr {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        }

        #myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <h2>My Customers</h2>
        <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="filter()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
        <table id="myTable">
            <tr class="header">
                <th style="width:60%; align:center;">Name</th> 
            </tr>
            <?php   
                if ($file = opendir('C:/wamp/www/example.com/Library')) {
                    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($file))) {
                        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td href='#'>
                                    <a href='http://qlhc3kppkxushjyg.onion/example.com/Library/<?php echo $entry; ?>'><?php echo $entry; ?></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr> 
                        <?php }
                    } 
                    closedir($file);
                }  
            ?>  
        </table>
        <script>
            function filter() {
                var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
                input = document.getElementById("myInput");
                filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                table = document.getElementById("myTable");
                tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
                for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                    if (td) {
                        if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                            tr[i].style.display = "";
                        } else {
                            tr[i].style.display = "none";
                        }
                    }       
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for tip I will remove path from Library and thank you very much.